# Bounce Castle jdk18on encrypt/sign email

Tags: java, java-8, sign, castle, bounce

I want to find a way how to encrypt/sign email with using bounce castle library in the newest version. In net there are only examples how to do it in previously version of library (jdk15on), but new version is no compatible with previous. Different api/classes at all. Is there anyone who can help in this area?

Comment: https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java has bc-java/mail/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/examples/CreateSignedMail.java. That works in Java 16

Comment: Yep. I just found the same. Thanks